# Required transformation and regression for non-normal variable

Tags: regression, data-transformation

My question is two-fold:

1. Should I transform the non-normal variables in the dataset (described below)? If so, how?
2. How does this affect the regression model that I need to use?

---

**The Dataset**

I have a dataset that is non-normal in some of the independent variables and the dependent variable. An example distribution of one of the non-normal independent variables is below:

[image]

All of the independent and dependent non-normal variables are events that happen infrequently (i.e. the most frequent value is often 0/1/2) and so do not have negative values. A comparable event would be a goal in a football match i.e. lots of low values, non-negative, can be 0, etc.

---

**What I have done so far**

Just to be clear, I am not an expert...that is why I am here. I am trying to learn (independently, unf)...with that said, I will briefly describe what I have done so far.

I am using an OLS linear regression model. My first question is just whether I should be doing this? I am modelling count data (events) so would something like Poisson regression be preferred? Why?

Second, how should I be transforming this data? I tried normalizing the independent variables (I am using Python, I used scikit-learn - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#normalization). This seemed to have no/negative effect on the output. Would a log transformation be more appropriate here? A log transformation appears to generate a more "normal-looking" distribution...is this better? If so, why?

On a kind of tangential point, if I normalize the dataset as above...do I still need an intercept? With event data, it seems like the intercept should be zero because no events means 0 dependent variable...but I am not sure.

Thanks. I suspect that I will get pilloried for being too vague so I am happy answer any additional questions about the dataset.

EDIT: maybe I should add that the reason I have gone down this route is that the QQ plot for the above model looks a bit like - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot#/media/File:Normal_exponential_qq.svg - the centre is on the line but the start and finish are curved upwards.

Comment: For starters, could you explain what it might mean for a "dataset" to be "non-linear in ... [a] variable"?

Comment: Is that more clear? I meant non-normal...I think (that is why I included the picture).

Comment: OLS regression does not assume normality of $Y$ or $X$  variables, it assumes normality of the residuals. Given the latter, the former can have any old (i.i.d.) distribution.

Comment: Right...maybe I have misunderstood something but, as I say above, when I examined the QQ plot of the model residuals it was curved upwards at both the end and start. And just examining the predicted values, the range of predictions was much tighter than the actual data i.e. it just predicted values within a range of 1-2 when the dependent variable ranged from 0-8 (I don't have the exact numbers to hand).

Comment: The tighter range of predicted values is a consequence of $R^{2}\ne1$... your predictors **do not explain the entirety of the variation in $Y$.** Again: if your *residuals* are distributed normally, linear regression assumes *nothing* about the distributions of $Y$ and $X$ other than that they are i.i.d..